# How to write a query in BigQuery that will INSERT a schema in from another table from within SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, nested

**[VERY NOVICE AT BIGQUERY/SQL WRITING]**

Hi,

I am using this dataset/query in [bigquery](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=aws-lambda-equalievent):

dataset/query

```
  select * from fh-bigquery.reddit.subreddits limit 10;
```

I am being asked to write a query that will INSERT a schema using the above table, that will have the following JSON schema structure in the new table:

```
schema: {
    fields: [
      {
        mode: NULLABLE, 
        name: dt, 
        type: DATE
      }, 
      {
        mode: NULLABLE, 
        name: num_comments, 
        type: INTEGER
      }, 
      {
        mode: NULLABLE, 
        name: posts, 
        type: INTEGER
      }, 

      {
        mode: NULLABLE, 
        name: ups, 
        type: INTEGER
      }, 
      {
        mode: NULLABLE, 
        name: downs, 
        type: INTEGER
      }, 
      {
        fields: [
          {
            mode: NULLABLE, 
            name: ups, 
            type: INTEGER
          }, 
          {
            mode: NULLABLE, 
            name: downs, 
            type: INTEGER
          }
        ], 
        mode: REPEATED, 
        name: subreddit_metrics, 
        type: RECORD
      }
    ]
  },
```

The `subreddit_metrics` field is nested as per the JSON above.

This query is from the BigQuery documentation, that shows me how to create nested fields for a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydataset.mytable(
    id STRING,
    first_name STRING,
    last_name STRING,
    dob DATE,
    addresses
      ARRAY<
        STRUCT<
          status STRING,
          address STRING,
          city STRING,
          state STRING,
          zip STRING,
          numberOfYears STRING>>)
    OPTIONS (description = 'Example name and addresses table')
```

Per the original request, to write a query that will INSERT a schema based off the original dataset/query above, I cant create a nested field from within a SELECT statement to CREATE a new table with the nested fields. Like so:

```
CREATE TABLE
    mydataset.test AS
  SELECT
    subreddit ARRAY< STRUCT< ups STRING,
    downs STRING,
  FROM
    fh-bigquery.reddit.subreddits;

Error:  Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword ARRAY at [12:15]
```

Questions:

```
1. Am I understanding the question correctly, in regards to writing a query that will INSERT a schema from another table in question? 

2. If my understanding of #1 is correct, how can I INSERT a schema from another table,with the right nesting, I would think using a CREATE statement with the help from a SELECT statement, right?
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my best quess. `subreddit_metrics` schema can be made by `ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(ups, downs))`.

```sql
SELECT subr AS subreddit,
       created_utc AS dt,
       num_comments,
       c_posts AS posts,
       ups,
       downs,
       ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(ups, downs)) OVER(PARTITION BY subr) AS subreddit_metrics
  FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit.subreddits`
;
```